# Why my sign up form shows an error when I use it

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am doing a project in windows forms for a sign up sheet but when I run the code it shows up an error.
This is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\RAV21001310\\OneDrive\\Database1.accdb;"))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("insert into tblUser (Username,Password,Gender,Age,FirstName,Last name) values('"+username.Text+"','"+password.Text+"','"+gender.Text+"','"+age Text+"','"+FirstName.Text+"','"+lastname.Text+"')"))
            {
                
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var login = new login();

                login.Show();

                this.Close();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error  " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I checked and I have the right amount of brackets etc and it doesn't show any red bits on the code but when I run it I get this error:
[Picture of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8k0N.jpg)

Comment: Please tell us what error has occurred that we can understand it better.

Comment: I have a warning light flashing on my car - please can you tell me what is wrong with it? (Or maybe you need a bit more information).

Comment: OK - so now we have a little more information - but still not enough. It would be so very very useful to have the full exception error message.

Comment: I can't show the full message since its on my college computer but when I remove the command.executenonquery line it doesn't show an error but it doesn't add the data into the database either.

Comment: Without the ExecuteNonQuery command then of course it won't insert the data into the database - that is the method that executes the SQL command. Without the full text of the Exception error message then it will be almost impossible to help you.

Comment: Sorry but without the exact error message it can be everything (like spelling mistakes etc.).

Comment: "I can't show the full message since its on my college computer" can you read it from the screen?

Comment: I have added the error message now

Answer (score 1):

Your Insert syntax is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO tblUser 
WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password AND Gender=@Gender AND Age=@Age AND FirstName=@FirstName AND LastName=@LastName
```

This makes no sense. Instead you may be looking for something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblUser (UserName, Password, Gender, Age, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @Gender, @Age, @FirstName, @LastName)
```

[Microsoft's page on INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is overly complicated. Here's a link that may be easier to understand: https://www.sqlshack.com/insert-into-t-sql-statement-in-sql-server/